# Terminology - idempotent and nilpotent maps

Tags: functions, terminology

Recall that a map $f:X\to X$ is idempotent when $f(f(x)) = f(x)$. Is there a standard term for maps where, for some $n$ possibly bigger than $1$, for all $x$ one has $f( f^{n}(x)) = f^n(x)$? I am thinking either "idempotent of order k" or "k-idempotent"

Likewise for nilpotent. It's defined for matrices as: A matrix is nilpotent when $A^k = 0$ for some positive integer $k$. Is there a standard terminology to make the $k$ explicit, such as "nilpotent of order k" or "k-nilpotent"?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a comment, perhaps it might inspire some terminology. This concept of "higher order" idempotent maps arises naturally, if one considers a set as set of states of some system and a map as a transformation that acts on a state (element) of the system. Now, a normal idempotent is the transformation under which a system reaches its "equilibrium" state at most after 1 step. Higher order idempotent just refers to situations when a system reaches equilibrium at most after k steps.

Comment: Here you go: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/10/can_you_describe_this_idempote.html